# preg_match functions doesn't work properly

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to filter all the letters and special characters, and only allow numbers. But whenever I pass a 0 as a variable, it is returning me false.

```
 $string = 0;
   if(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string) == true){
      echo 'True';
   }else{
      echo 'False';
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)**

> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise
> subject will be returned unchanged or NULL if an error occurred.

When you check `preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string) == true` it is checking the string `'0'` after it has been stripped of all non-numeric characters (still `'0'`) and seeing if it evaluates to `TRUE`. The string `'0'` and the int `0` both evaluate to `FALSE`. I.e `'0' == FALSE && 0 == FALSE`. This is why your condition is returning `FALSE` since `'0' == FALSE`.

You can change your condition to this instead: `preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string) != ''`

Now you will be checking to see if your string is empty after filtering out all non-numeric characters I.e if your string contained only non-numeric characters it would return `FALSE`.

Comment: I'm doubting if this will do exactly what you want - I may have misunderstood. This will only return false when the string contains ONLY non-numeric characters. Should it return `FALSE` when there are ANY non-numeric characters?